# How should I structure my code when using SQL Alchemy and Reflection?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I appologize for this question being slightly lengthy. The TLDR is:

- I am struggling to understand how to structure my code when using the reflection features of SQL Alchemy ORM
- This is because in order to construct "an instance of a table type" I appear to have to pass around a `metadata` object, rather than "just being able to use the type" as you would any other Python type
- This might be necessary, becuase the types are not known statically (when the Python code has been written)
- but I am seeking further advice becuase this is unfamiliar to me and I do not really know what I am doing

#### End of TLDR

I'm struggling slighly with understanding exactly what the intention is in regards to how I should structure my code when working with SQL Alchemy and Reflection.

When using Reflection, types are dynamically created at runtime by Python depending on the structure of a table in an SQL database.

Because my types are only available when I execute my code, and not when I write it, I am having a bit of a conceptual block as to how to structure it.

The minimum amount of code required to perform a reflection operation and obtain an object representing a type is something like the following:

```
db_url = "postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/postgresdb"

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url=db_url)
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
my_table_object = sqlalchemy.Table('my_table', metadata, autoload_with=engine)

with engine.connect() as connection:

    # rest of code
```

`my_table_object` can now be used to perform CRUD:

```
query = sqlalchemy.select(my_table_object)
result_proxy = connection.execute(query)
result_set = result_proxy.fetchall()

print(result_set[0])
```

#### My existing code:

Most of my existing code has been written without using any of the ORM features of SQL Alchemy. This means that I was working exclusively with the `text` object and SQL DSL code.

For example, I have functions which look a bit like this:

```
def select_id_from_my_table(connection: sqlalchemy.Connection):

    query_string = text(
        '''
            select id
                from my_table
        '''
    )

    query_params = { }

    result = connection.execute(query_string, query_params)
    
    # do something with result and return value(s)
```

Rather than passing the `engine` around, I decided to pass a single `connection` object. This is for two reasons:

- This is a single thread process (it's Python - and no libraries such as multiprocess are being used)
- There doesn't seem to be a lot of point adding additional latency by opening and closing the connection to perform database operations when I can just keep a single connection open for the lifetime of my program (opening it at the top level in the `def main` function and passing it around the call stack)

As an asside, I am assuming this is a sensible design. If it isn't, please do leave a comment.

#### Adding ORM code:

The following line of code (taken from the first snippet) effectively creates a Python type. (A factory?)

```
my_table_object = sqlalchemy.Table('my_table', metadata, autoload_with=engine)
```

The question I have is how is it intended to be worked with?

- My previous code which just use SQL requires me to pass a `connection` object around the call stack. This is not too arduous.

If I want to now work with the ORM functionality, I have to either:

- Create my table types using reflection at the start of the code, or
- Create them "lazily" - only when needed

If I understand correctly the actual information about the reflected tables is stored in the `metadata` object, as well as being returned by the function call to `sqlalchemy.Table()`.

If I choose the first option, and create all required tables at the beginning, I now need to pass these objects around my call stack just to have access to them when needed.

There appear to be two choices to do this:

- create some new structure to hold the reflected table types (a dict would do fine)
- pass the `metadata` object around, which has a `tables` attribute, from which the table "types" can be obtained:

```
my_table_object = metadata.tables.get('my_table')
```

The second option appears to be more sensible - pass the `metadata` object around.

This then leads to the previous question being somewhat redundant. Creating the tables lazily requires some additional code to check if the table type object has been created every time we want to use it, so we might as well just reflect all the required tables at the beginning.

#### Summary:

I have described above a possible way that the dynamic runtime reflection features of SQL Alchemy *could be used*. However it seems a bit strange to me for the following reasons:

- To interact with the database I need to pass around a `connection` object
- To use the ORM features, I now need to pass around a `metadata` object just to get access to the "types" (***)
- If I want to create another connection, or perform further reflection operations, I also need to pass around the `engine` object
- There doesn't seem to be a way to use the `connection` object to perform the reflection operations
- These points lead to writing code where at least 3 objects are being passed around at all levels of the call stack, in case they are needed somewhere
- I could of course wrap them in a tuple, or some more structured type. A more structured type leads to a lot of additional code which needs to be written, and likely a more rigid overall structure. This isn't obviously a good thing, especially in a language which is designed to be very flexible.

(***) This point should be stressed further: I find this really weird. Usually types are "globally" accessable from anywhere in a Python code. If I want to construct a `MyClass` type, provided I have correctly imported `MyClass` from the source code where it is defined, I can just use it anywhere I like. I do not "have to pull the `MyClass` thing out from some `metadata` object.

It might be that this style of programming is just unfamilar to me and therefore it seems strange, and there is nothing wrong with this approach, and that it is indeed necessary to structure things this way.

###### Note:

Please note that I am aware there are an additional two ways to work with the SQL Alchemy ORM, both of which can be used to define tables at "compile" time (when the code is written - Python does not have a compiler). I suppose you might describe this as a "static" definition rather than a dynamic one using reflection at runtime.

*I do not want to do this. I want to leverage the "code" (metadata/structure) which is already inside my SQL database to define the table structure for me.*

This leads to less maintainance overhead because if the SQL Database structure changes, often no code changes are required, unless the logic needs to be changed. There is little point in using a dynamic language such as Python to then not leverage its dynamic features. (Although the reverse approach would make perfect sense if you were using Python code to drive the creation of a database.)

Answer (score 0):

While thinking about this a bit I came up with quite a nice design.

This is not a full answer to the question I asked. It is more of a "work around" solution - but it is quite nice so I thought it to be worth sharing.

I previously said that creating more rigid structure doesn't necessarily lead to a better design or an easier to work with codebase. While this is true, having something which acts as a bridge between the dynamically generated and static code could be advantageous.

- the dynamic code (obtained from the reflection operation which performs a query to the database) is not known at runtime
- but we want to write some Python code, which is static and the logic is defined before runtime
- a nice solution to this might be to create some kind of interface between the two parts
- this doesn't solve the original question asked which was related to how to get access to the dynamically created "type objects", but as a side-effect it does provide some new type which can be accessed from anywhere, thus side-stepping the problem

```
import sqlalchemy


TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_schema'
TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
FULLY_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAME = f'{TABLE_SCHEMA}.{TABLE_NAME}'


class MyTable:

    def __init__(self, engine: sqlalchemy.Engine, metadata: sqlalchemy.MetaData) -> None:

        # check to see if the table has been reflected already
        if FULLY_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAME in metadata.tables:
            print(f'{FULLY_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAME} metadata object already created')
        else:
            print(f'{FULLY_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAME} creating metadata object')

            # if the table has not been reflected yet (does not exist
            # in the metadata object) perform reflection operation
            my_table_object = \
                sqlalchemy.Table(TABLE_NAME, metadata, schema=TABLE_SCHEMA, autoload_with=engine)

        # metadata should now contain the reflected table
        my_table_object = \
            metadata.tables.get(FULLY_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAME)

        # save a direct reference to the table "type object"
        # for later use (slightly more efficient than saving
        # a reference to the whole metadata)
        self.my_table_object = \
            my_table_object

    # an example CRUD operation
    def select(self, connection: sqlalchemy.Connection) -> list:

        query = self.search_query_table_object.select()
        result_proxy = connection.execute(query)
        result_set = result_proxy.fetchall()
        result_list = list(result_set)

        return result_list

    # define other operations, insert, update, upsert, or operations of
    # arbitrary complexity here
```

Since `MyTable` is a static type, we can import it from anywhere and use it as any other traditional static type.